# golang: dynamic composition of variadic function parameter

Tags: go

I'd like to call a variadic function and compose the parameter dynamically. Take `fmt.Printf()` for example. if I have a `struct`:

```
type Foo struct {
   a int
   b string
}
```

I'd like to call `fmt.Printf(foo.a, foo.b).` But if I have another `Bar struct` with 3 fields, I'd like to call `fmt.Printf(bar.a, bar.b, bar.c)`.

So I'd like to write a function like this:

```
func MyPrint(obj interface{})
```

and be able to call it with `MyPrint(foo)` or `MyPrint(bar)` and the code will automatically figure out that `foo` has 2 fields and do:

```
...
fmt.Printf(foo.a, foo.b)
```

`bar` has 3 fields and do

```
...
fmt.Printf(bar.a, bar.b, bar.c)
```

In Python you can do something like `call(*list)`. How can I achieve this in Go?

Comment: are you trying to create a function that accept any kinds of struct? if that so simple use `[]interface`

Comment: @GujaratSantana Yes. But `[] interface` cannot be accepted by `func(params ... interface{}`

Comment: what exacly do you mean by dynamic composition? `func boo(params ...interface{}){}` seems to solve your problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use ellipsis operator

```
slice := []Type{Type{}, Type{}}
call(slice...)
```

for function

```
func(arg ...Type) {}
```